# What are some ways to copy and paste more efficiently on iOS?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, copy-paste

If I am going to do some Google research on a question I have, I would like to copy a bunch of links I encounter and have them all go into some kind of list somewhere. Then, when I have gathered enough links, I can paste them in a document somewhere. That way, I don’t have to tediously switch back and forth between two apps, constantly.

Ideally, beyond just links, there would be the titles of the webpages, and some descriptions of them, too.

What are some ways to do this? The app Copied has some decent functionality related to this, but limited. Could it be pulled off with Shortcuts?

Comment: Have you considered using bookmarks in your browser? Or using something like pocket/Instapaper?

Comment: Bookmarks are decent of course, but I like the ability to paste text in a document which I might write up for myself. I’ll check out Pocket/Instapaper, although if it’s just a bookmark system, then it’s not my ideal - still useful though, sure. Thx

Comment: I use Drafts on iOS and the [quick capture extension](https://docs.getdrafts.com/docs/extensions/share.html) is great for this.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using iPhone or iPad?

If you are using iPad, you should be able to do that. The iOS (or now called iPadOS) in iPad allows you to run 2 apps side by side at the same time. You can copy and paste the info between those 2 apps easily.

If you are using iPhone / iPod Touch, seems no workaround other than copy and paste the link one by one like what you are doing it now.

https://www.apple.com/ipados/
https://www.macrumors.com/guide/ipados-tips-and-tricks/

**Update:** Maybe you can try this method? https://www.matthewcassinelli.com/ios-clipboard-shortcuts-copied/

Comment: cassinelli link seems good. Thx very much

Answer (score 1):

You can use Notes.app for this.

1. Create note (optional) “Research thing”
2. Navigate to a website
3. Click share, select Notes.app (option to add notes to the default share menu for easier access)
4. Select the note you want the link in, and then add any relevant text

You’ll now have an editable note with links containing previews of the content.

[image: screenshot showing saving link to note]